# Highcharts center yaxis value at zero on column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, column-chart

I want to center YAxis value at zero on Highcharts Column chart with positive & negative values like this: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_IZwAPijvleZzBhUnVaSFhBcDQ,
these axis values are dynamic loaded.
With jqPlot there is an option called forceTickAt0 at axis settings that can meet my requirements,
I'd like to know if this is possible with Highcharts, if yes how to do?
Thanks.

**Update:**
Ok, in order to clearly explain my question, I've created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kdcevyu1/2/).
As you see on the chart, the max/min series value at y-axis is 5001/-4280, but Highcharts shows 15000/-5000 at y-axis boundary and I expect it to be 6000/-5000, and if you remove the first value 5001 from y-axis series, Highcharts will show 5000/-5000 at y-axis boundary that's what I expected. So add a 5001 value at y-axis series causes the y-axis boundary becomes too far away.

The key point is I don't want the biggest/smallest series value at y-axis got too much far away from chart max/min boundary value.

Following is the code, for explanation purpose, series data here use fixed values, In a real situation they are all dynamic loaded.

```
$(function() {
   $('#container').highcharts({
     chart: {
       zoomType: 'xy',
       plotBackgroundColor: '#fffdf6',
       alignTicks: true,
     },
     title: {
       text: 'Country Illegally Building Num Average Tax',
     },
     subtitle: {
       text: ''
     },
     xAxis: [{
       categories: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N'],
       crosshair: true,
       title: {
         text: 'Country Code',
       }
     }],
     yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
       labels: {
         format: '{value} ',
       },
       title: {
         text: 'Illegally Building Num',
       },

     }, { // Secondary yAxis
       min: 0, //Required to start at zero
       title: {
         text: 'Average Tax ($)',
         style: {
           color: '#666'
         }
       },
       labels: {
         format: '{value} $',
         style: {
           color: '#666'
         }
       },
       opposite: true
     }],
     tooltip: {
       shared: true
     },
     legend: {
       enabled: false
     },
     series: [{
       color: 'red',
       negativeColor: 'green',
       name: 'Illegally Building Num',
       type: 'column',
       data: [5001, 369, 475, 891, 3585, 4235, -1711, -3648, -3749, -2555, -4280, -1017, 2001, -900],
       tooltip: {
         valueSuffix: ' '
       }
     }, {
       name: 'Average Tax',
       type: 'line',
       data: [140.5, 141, 139.5, 162, 151, 142, 147, 151, 154, 142, 146, 149, 153, 111.5],
       yAxis: 1,
       tooltip: {
         valueSuffix: ' $'
       }
     }]
   });
});
```

Comment: 1) the min/max is not an absolute. It works in combination with the *tickInterval* and the *minPadding* / *maxPadding*. In most cases, if you set the max as described, you will get a "friendly" max. If you don't, you can influence it by adjusting the tickInterval and maxPadding values.

Comment: The max/min value very depends on the raw data, and it's difficult to adjust the tickInterval coz y-axis values may get big difference (maybe just 1,000, 10,000, 100,000, or 1,000,000...etc)

Comment: have you tried setting a min and max? if that isn't working how you want, post a fiddle with specifics. have you tried just plotting the data and not bothering doing anything else? It seems like what you're asking for is normal default behavior for Highcharts - again, if it's not working how you want, post a fiddle with more specific details about what is not working as you need.

Comment: OK, seeing your update - you didn't mention that you're using a dual y-axis chart. This is 1) a bad idea (generally), and 2) important to fixing your problem.  Take a look at the **alignTicks** property:  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks

Comment: Yes, dual y-axis chart is required in this case, and y-axis & y-axis2 must have same tick count, this is why I set alignTicks to true. If alignTicks set to false, y-axis & y-axis2 will get different tick count that's not expected. With jqPlot dual y-axis its easily to just specify forceiTickAt0 to true, and with Highcarts seems no such an easily way to do this.

Comment: the result of all this is a chart that doesn't make sense :) but you are correct in that there is not one easy setting to do what you want. But we've given you the relevant settings that you need to work with. In addition, look through the docs at the various axis scaling control properties.

Comment: Please see my original pic link, its plotted using jqPlot with two y-axis and have same tick count _without_ specifying any min/max value.

Comment: Ok. But Highcharts is not jqPlot. Not sure what else you want here. Highcharts does not appear to have the single setting you're looking for. There are a number of different settings you can manipulate to achieve. Give it a go.

Comment: Could you please give me some related setting that may achieve this? I really prefer Highcharts charts but I'm afraid I cannot accomplish this with luck. Thank you very much.

Comment: To recap: tickInterval; min; max; alignTicks; tickAmount; minPadding; maxPadding; tickPixelInterval.  Look at the docs:  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis

Comment: @DogyCat If you need better control over ticks, then you might be interested in using tickPositioner - API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner If you are still having problems, then it will be easier to answer your question if you could write requirements in short, precise points.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a forceiTickAt0, but this functionality can easily be accomplished by setting the min/max of the y-axis. For example:

```
yAxis: {
            min:-20,
            max:20,
            title: {
                text: 'Axis Title'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value + '°';
                }
            },
            lineWidth: 2
        },
```

This would have a center point at 0, and depending on your data you can dynamically set the max to be the absolute value of the min.